# Microsoft SQL Server Error 18056, Login failed password did not match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We are using SQL Server 2012 Standard version.

Yesterday our web-servers can't connect DB server. 
So I check EventLog of DB server.

We got an Error:

> The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 57, which had been
>   reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 8. This error may have
>   been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for
>   failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> EventID:18056

And also got this Information Message:

> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for
>   the login provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.100]

We checked and sa password is correct.

We didn't do anything, but sometimes after all web-servers can connect DB server again.

Can anyone let me know what is the reason?

Comment: Don't know the awnser to your question but it seems to me it's just as likely for some reason the webserver sent the wrong password to the database server. Therefor I suggest you put some tags on the post refering to the web solution.

Comment: Your error message suggests that you are actually *using* the "sa" account. *Don't*. "sa" is the built-in administrator account that should not be used by either applications or end users. Use integrated authentication instead, or dedicated SQL server accounts added to the `sysadmin` role for administration. If your web server is connecting to SQL Server with an account that has administrative privileges, that's a big security no-no.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but in my last job I saw some weird things with connection pooling. Specifically sometimes when IIS or an app was restarted it would throw similar errors except it would also throw a lot of trigger errors where a SQL login was denied due to trigger execution.

If you're getting stonewalled and have access I would try to get the application and web server logs, copy them over and pore over them. The first time I thought it was SQL, but then it happened again after someone admitted to restarting an app and that gave it away.